# Automating Tasks in Response to Facebook Messenger Messages

Tags: automation, scripting, chatbot, messaging, facebook-messenger

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm exploring the possibility of automating certain tasks in response to incoming messages on my Facebook Messenger. Here's an overview of the workflow I have in mind:

Extract the sender's name from incoming messages.
Apply a specific algorithm to modify data based on the extracted name.
Send a message to a designated Facebook group with the modified data.
Notify the original sender when the task is complete by monitoring the group for my username tag and a specific keyword like "done" or "finished."
I'm open to using any automation tool or scripting language that can efficiently accomplish this task. If you have experience with any tools or methods that could be suitable for this purpose, I'd greatly appreciate your guidance. Additionally, if you can provide insights into best practices or potential challenges associated with automating interactions with Facebook Messenger, that would be valuable.

Thank you for your assistance!

What I've tried:

I've started by researching potential automation tools or scripting languages that could be suitable for this task. However, I haven't yet implemented any specific solution as I'm looking for guidance on the best approach.

What I'm expecting:

I'm hoping to receive recommendations or insights into automation tools or methods that could efficiently accomplish the described workflow. Additionally, any advice on best practices or potential challenges associated with automating interactions with Facebook Messenger would be highly appreciated.